# How to dismiss the Kivy pop-up via a Button?

Tags: python, button, popup, kivy, dismiss

I have a pop-up created with Kivy, which contains 2 buttons.  User can dismiss the pop-up by pressing outside of the pop-up area (auto_dismiss = True), or by clicking the "No" button.
Selecting the "Yes" button, will exit the whole application.

Please see relevant code:

```
class ExitApp(App):

def exit_confirmation(self):

    # popup can only have one Widget.  This can be fixed by adding a BoxLayout

    self.box_popup = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')

    self.box_popup.add_widget(Label(text = "Really exit?"))

    self.box_popup.add_widget(Button(
        text = "Yes",
        on_press = ExitApp.exit,
        size_hint = (0.215, 0.075)))

    self.box_popup.add_widget(Button(
        text = "No",
        on_press = self.popup_exit.dismiss,
        size_hint=(0.215, 0.075)))

    self.popup_exit = Popup(title = "Exit",
        content = self.box_popup,
        size_hint = (0.4, 0.4),
        auto_dismiss = True)

    self.popup_exit.open()

def exit(self):

    App.get_running_app().stop()
```

The problem now lays with pressing the "No" button.  When that is pressed, the code exits with this error:

> ```
>  on_press = self.popup_exit.dismiss,
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'popup_exit'

Any idea how I can fix this as easily as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue by a lazy function

```
on_press = lambda *args: self.popup_exit.dismiss()
```

This way, the lookup will occur **only** when the button is pressed and *popup_exit* is already in place...

Comment: The lambda function did not help here...  Please see my answer without the lambda function.  Any idea how lambda could be used then in this example?

Comment: @ElFred Put the line from my answer instead of the line that fails in yours... if it doesn't work, post the new error...

Comment: Your suggestion fails with this error: "TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)"

Comment: @ElFred - add *args to ignore the button argument

Comment: Excellent!  That did solve the lambda problem!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change `on_press = self.popup_exit.dismiss` to `on_press = lambda: self.popup_exit.dismiss()` because dismiss is a function and needs to be called when the button is pressed.

```
def exit_confirmation(self):


    # popup can only have one Widget.  This can be fixed by adding a BoxLayout

    self.box_popup = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')

    self.box_popup.add_widget(Label(text = "Really exit?"))

    self.box_popup.add_widget(Button(
        text = "Yes",
        on_press = ExitApp.exit,
        size_hint = (0.215, 0.075)))

    self.popup_exit = Popup(title = "Exit",
        content = self.box_popup,
        size_hint = (0.4, 0.4),
        auto_dismiss = True)

    self.box_popup.add_widget(Button(
    text = "No",
    on_press = lambda: self.popup_exit.dismiss() ,
    size_hint=(0.215, 0.075)))

    self.popup_exit.open()
```

Comment: You should not call self.popup_exit.dismiss(), it will be called at evaluation time! not when the button is pressed, remove the parenthesis

Comment: I guess i have to delete the answer :)). Yeah i will edit again and consider that :) tnx

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  However, the lambda solution did not work...  I got this error instead:
" TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)".

But what did help, was to change the position of the "self.popup_exit...." code before the Button "add_widget" code, and then "on_press = self.popup_exit.dismiss,"

Comment: This is the solution, as given by Yoav Glazner in another answer!
on_press = lambda *args: self.popup_exit.dismiss()

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work in `kivy`?

```
on_press : root.dismiss()
```

Comment: Can you provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

#the best way i find to dismiss the Kivy pop-up via a Button is by define global

```
#Kivy         v2.0.0
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup



class GetPopUpFunctions(FloatLayout):

    def yes_click(self):
        print("banana")


    def no_click(self):
        print("closing the popup")
        self.close_popup()

    def close_popup(self):
        admin_popup.dismiss()





class AdminScreen(Screen):
    """
    Description:
    Owner:Yaki Hakimi

    """

    def open_popup(self):

        popup_functions = GetPopUpFunctions() # Create a new instance of the pop class
        global admin_popup
        admin_popup = Popup(title="Magnets", content=popup_functions, size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400))
        admin_popup.open()


GUI = Builder.load_string("""


GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager


        AdminScreen:#name of the class
            name: "admin_screen"
            id: admin_screen


<AdminScreen>:

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width,  root.height

        Button:
            text : "popup debug"
            on_press :
                root.open_popup()

##############################################################
<GetPopUpFunctions>:

    Label:
        text:"popup message"
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}

    Button:
        text: "Yes"
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.45, "y":0.4}
        on_release:
            root.yes_click()


    Button:
        text: "No"
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.45, "y":0.1}
        on_release:
            root.no_click()




""")


class PopupOpenClose(App):


    def build(self):
        return GUI


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PopupOpenClose().run()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `on_press = self.popup.dismiss()` in replacement of `on_press = self.popup_exit.dismiss`

Comment: Not correct,  it will be called at evaluation time!