# Dismiss Pop Up Window in Kivy

Tags: python, class, popup, kivy, dismiss

I am trying to dismiss a pop up window in KV language. I have tried creating a function but am having trouble calling the popup window's instance because it is not its own class object. I also tried utilizing the factory module but that won't work either because that will only let me use one widget in the pop up window for some reason. Below is my code:

Python file:

```
class SettingsWindow(Screen):
pretty_list_people = StringProperty ("")
pretty_list_jobs = StringProperty ("")

def get_Jobs(self):
    return WindowManager.jobs

def get_People(self):
    return WindowManager.people

def Pretty_Print_People(self, ppl_list):
    self.pretty_list_people = ""
    for person in ppl_list:
        self.pretty_list_people += person + "\n"

def Pretty_Print_Jobs(self, job_list):
    self.pretty_list_jobs = ""
    for job in job_list:
        self.pretty_list_jobs += job + "\n"

def show_popup(self):
    show = PopupAddJob()
    popupWindow = Popup(title="Add Job", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 200))
    popupWindow.open()

def dismiss_popup(self):
    self.popupWindow.dismiss()
```

kv File:

```
<PopupAddJob>:
Label:
    text: "You pressed a button"
    size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
    pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}
TextInput:
    id: add_job
    multiline: False
    size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
    pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "y":0.5}
Button:
    text: "Close"
    on_press:add_job.focus=True
    on_press: SettingsWindow.dismiss_popup() # <<<<<<<<<< *** PROBLEM IS HERE ***
    size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
    pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "y":0.3}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `self.dismiss()` work?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `root.dismiss()` because `self` would refer to the button and you need to refer to the `PopupAddJob`

Comment: That does not work. I think it is because root is not referring to the pop up object itself, but rather the class object "PopupAddJob" which is a FloatLayout not a pop up. Thus, a FloatLayout does not have a dismiss method.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41583481/6464041)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `dismiss_popup()` method you are referencing `self.popupWindow`, but you have not created such an attribute. Perhaps you should create that reference in the `show_popup()` method:

```
def show_popup(self):
    show = PopupAddJob()
    self.popupWindow = Popup(title="Add Job", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 200))
    self.popupWindow.open()
```

Comment: I tried this and got this:  `File "C:\Users\Anthony DeArmas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\Anthony DeArmas\Desktop\assigner\assigner.kv", line 208, in <module>
     on_press: root.dismiss_popup()
   File "C:\Users\Anthony DeArmas\Desktop\assigner\assigner.py", line 67, in dismiss_popup
     SettingsWindow.popupWindow.dismiss()
 AttributeError: type object 'SettingsWindow' has no attribute 'popupWindow'`

Comment: You still need to change your `kv` to access the `SettingsWindow` instance. The code you posted is trying to access the `SettingsWindow` class (not the instance). I can't tell how you might access the instance, since you haven't posted the rest of your code.